# Test Data not being found when running a test

Tags: apex, soql, unit-test, batch, failing-tests

I'm writing a test class for a batch class, however I'm running into issues when it comes to the test data. Code more or less looks like this:

```java
@isTest
public static void testMethod(){
    Box__c b = new Box__c;
    insert b;

    List<Box__c> boxes = new List<Box__c>();
    boxes.add(b);

    List<Chocolate__c> chocolates = new List<Chocolate__c>();

    for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++){
        Chocolate__c c = new Chocolate__c();
        c.Name = 'Chocolate '+ i;
        c.Box__c = b.Id;
        c.Contains_Nuts__c = true;
        chocolates.add(c);
    }

    insert chocolates;
    system.debug(chocolates);

    Test.startTest();
    Database.executeBatch(new WhatsInTheBoxBatch(boxes) );
    Test.stopTest();
}
```

The WhatsInTheBoxBatch constructor should then attempt to query for all the Chocolate__c records that were created, but it keeps not finding anything.

```java
global class WhatsInTheBoxBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful{

    public WhatsInTheBoxBatch(){}

    public WhatsInTheBoxBatch(List<Box__c> boxes){

        Set<Id> boxIds = Set<Id>();
        for(Box__c b : boxes){
            boxIds.add(b.Id);
        }

        List<Chocolate__c> chocos = new List<Chocolate__c>();
        for(Chocolate__c c : [SELECT Id FROM Chocolate__c WHERE Box__c IN : boxIds AND Contains_Nuts__c = true]){
            chocos.add(c);
        }
        if(!chocos.isEmpty()){
            // construct another query here to pass into start() method

        } else if{
            system.debug('no chocolates found');

        }

    }
```

Does anyone know what might be going wrong here? I keep ending up in the 'no chocolates found' debug when running the test. When I actually anonymous execute the batch it finds Chocolate__c records and works fine.

I've also confirmed that the `system.debug(chocolates)` shows them inserted correctly with the correct Box__c Id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, someone had an existing Flow that would affect `Contains_Nuts__c`. In my case it was setting it as false on all my records, hence why the query would not find anything.

Thank you to all those who commented and tried helping!